# Going lines/paths to one in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have started learning Illustrator since a while back and one thing is bothering me and stopping me from designing stuff. Also I am not native English speaking so I am having a hard time to find the correct search term.

I'll try my best. I have these two lines, one is from a circle and one is just a straight line I drew into that circle. And what I want to do is join them so that they are one smooth line. See the image down below.

[image]

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't physically join an open path such as a straight line, to a closed path such as a circle, in vector image editing software. It's not possible.

Instead you should use snapping to make sure the anchors overlap. Enable Smart Guides, and Snap to Point in the View menu.

I suspect the main problem you are experiencing is because you have Align Art to Pixel Grid selected. Uncheck that setting before you draw your line. See example below highlighted in red.

Now snapping should work perfectly

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was a simple solution for something that seemed so hard. Thanks a lot!