# Join anchor points from different paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point

Is it possible to Join Anchor points "A" and "B" from following figure in Illustrator ?

Its for one of my swan drawing and I want to continue the path to make wing for swan.

I have tried using path join tool but It gives me error that "To join, you must select two end points of same or different paths".

If this is possible somehow please let me know.

Path to cloud file :- [Swan_art_link](https://shared-assets.adobe.com/link/7e0c90de-e456-46ad-5240-991677d889cb)
[image]

Comment: No. You can't have the end point of an open path join a node in a closed path. It's not possible in Illustrator, or any vector image editing software. The best you can do is make them overlap, or perhaps do that and then make a combined/compound path.

Comment: Also see: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/150448/going-lines-paths-to-one-in-illustrator/150449#150449 for the overlap solution.

Comment: Also related if you don't understand open versus closed paths: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/86468/open-path-outlines-and-closed-path-outlines-adobe-illustrator

Comment: Thanks for the links @BillyKerr. I was confused with Join tool and open paths, also it is not clearly mentioned in the Illustrator Classroom in a book 2021 Edition

Comment: Should I delete my duplicate question or leave it as is ?

Comment: No just leave it. No worries. The question is already closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible because **a path can't split into two at one anchor point.**

Illustrator tells you this in the error message: *you must select two end points*. Point B is not an *end point*, it's in the middle of a path.

What to do instead of course depends on what you are trying to achieve. Probably you should just let point A *overlap* point B. It's completely normal for a vector illustration to consist of several separate paths.

Comment: Thank you so much, I through I was not using the join tool correctly.